# PL/SQL - Cursor. Can't iterate through table (varchar argument)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, syntax, plsql, compiler-errors

I created a procedure to calculate the hashcode of a record (complete line of a table) and then update a column with the calculated hashcode number.

Here's my code at this point (which is based on some info I manage to gather from Google):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calcHashCode (inputTableString IN varchar2) IS
  c_data varchar2(3000);  --QUERY
  c_cursor sys_refcursor; --CURSOR
  c_record inputTableString%rowtype; -- Problem is here
BEGIN
  c_data := 'SELECT * FROM ' || inputTableString;

  OPEN c_cursor for c_data;

  LOOP
    FETCH c_cursor INTO c_record;
    EXIT WHEN c_cursor%notfound;

    -- will do stuff here with the records

    dbms_output.put_line('stuff');

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c_cursor;
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS

 4/13  PLS-00310: with %ROWTYPE attribute, 'INPUTTABELA' must name a table, cursor or cursor-variable
 4/13  PL/SQL: Item ignored
11/25  PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
11/5   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

So, my idea (for the final stage of the procedure) is to iterate through out the records, build a string with and then calculate the hashcode. After that, I'll run the update instruction.

The thing is at this point using a `varchar` as an argument and I'm not being able to iterate through the table in order to get my concatenate records.

Comment: If you are going to "do stuff", then you should know what the columns are that you are looking for.  As the error specifies, the `%ROWTYPE` requires a table, not a string representing a table name.

Comment: I understand. And that's what I'm trying to figure it out. I'm gonna try and query ALL_TAB_COLS to see if I can solve the problem that way. Fetching all the fields from the table and then calculate the hashcode that way.

It's something :) Thx for the reply.

Comment: If you are learning SQL and cursors, start with a simpler example.

Comment: :( it's for a work project :(

Comment: . . Perhaps you should ask another question and describe what needs to be done.  There may be some other way to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic cursors are the ugliest...

the problem is with that section:

```
  c_data varchar2(3000);  --QUERY
  c_cursor sys_refcursor; --CURSOR
  c_record inputTableString%rowtype;
```

i used something like this:

```
  TYPE t_data IS    REF CURSOR;
  cr_data           t_data;
  cr_data_rec       inputTableString%ROWTYPE;   --that table need to be exists in compile time
```

the rest are good i think

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered pushing the whole declaration and loop into an anonymous block that will then get executed by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE? You can then simplify your looping construct to a simple FOR loop too.

I'm away from my database at the moment, so excuse any syntax glitches, but something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calcHashCode (inputTableString IN varchar2) IS
  c_data varchar2(30000);  --QUERY
BEGIN
  c_data := '
        BEGIN
            FOR aRec IN
                 (SELECT * FROM ' || inputTableString ||' )
            LOOP
                --do your stuff
             END LOOP;
        END';
  execute immediate c_Data;
END;
/
```

It may not be pretty, and your "Stuff" may not easily be able to be fit into this construct, but it IS feasible

Comment: I have to try this idea.

I manage to solve the problem by creating a trigger before insert, It's not dynamic... but since I don't have to do this in a lot of tables... it does the trick...

 :NEW.HASHCODE := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE(StringToCalculate, 16, 1024);

Comment: The fun part will still be figuring out the StringToCalculate which may involve scanning all_tab_columns and building the SELECT to parse the correct columns. If doing it dynamically though, I'd have to ask - what happens when someone tacks an extra column onto the table at a later date? ALTER TABLE  won't fire the trigger to re-calculate your hash once per row if that is what you expect. Having pre-table triggers that hold the definitive list of columns to hash may be the most easily maintained solution in the end.

Answer (score -1):

You can do all this kind of stuff with PL/SQL package `DBMS_SQL`, however it is definitely not for beginners and you should start with something easier.

[Examples for DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i996963)

Comment: This is pretty cool, but way to complicated. But yes... it seems to do the trick :D thx for tip!